# Physics Impulse

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum

This is the problem I am dealing with:
"One of the functions of an automotive air bag is that it lengthens the collision time. Without an air bag, suppose the 100Ns impulse of a collision is taken up by a fairly rigid dashboard, requiring a time of 15 ms. Find the amount of force exerted on the passenger."

Up till this problem I have only dealt with problems using the equation F x Change in Time = Mass x Change in Velocity. This problem only gives me 2 of the 4 variables in that equation, so I am at a loss of how to figure it out. Please help!

Comment: remember the definition of impulse; this lets you continue.

Answer (score 2):

You're given the impulse and time, so simply susbtitute the given variables in the formula which calculates the impulse...

Which is

```
impulse = F * change in time
```

So... substitue the variables given to you and rearrange

```
100 = F * 15
F = 100 / 15
```